# Formatting Javascript output

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following code to output three form fields, but they appear on separate lines.  I need them to all appear on one line within a paragraph or with an html line break at the end.  I'm sure it is down to the li tag, but if I change that (e.g. to span) it makes no difference.  I also want each field to have different size specified.

I've added the whole page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  li {
    display: inline;
  }
  </style>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='../../js/dummy.js'></script>





  <style type='text/css'>
    input {display: block;}
ul {list-style-type: none;}
  </style>

<?php
/*
need to get three new inputs on a single line
need to append another line with incremented names for inputs each time the button is hit


*/
?>


<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
var myinput = document.getElementById("myinput");
    var form = document.getElementById("myform");
    var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var fakejson = JSON.stringify([{
                    "fieldname": "Part No.1"
                }, {
                    "fieldname": "Qty"
                }, {
                    "fieldname": "Description"
                }]);

    myinput.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
            if (evt.target.value == "+") {
                sucsess(fakejson);
            }
        });


    function appendform(name) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var newinput = document.createElement("input");
        newinput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        newinput.setAttribute('name', name);
        newinput.setAttribute('size', 60);
        li.textContent = name;
        li.appendChild(newinput);
       form.insertBefore(li, submit);


    }

    function sucsess(data) {

        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        for (key in json) {
            appendform(json[key]["fieldname"]);
        }
    }

}//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>

<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    print_r($_POST); echo "<br /><br />"; // print POST data received - delete in production
}
?>

  <ul>
    <form action="" id ="myform" method='post'>

        <input type="button" name="myinput" id="myinput" value='+' title='Add fields'>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">

</form>
</ul>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Can you please add your HTML output?

Comment: Each field is already on a new line - I don't want that!

Comment: @NickIredale The HTML output you added doesn't seem right... Where are the `<li>`'s that you add through Javascript? I would like to see your *final* HTML output after the Javascript has finished.

Comment: btw. move `<ul>` as child of `<form>`, otherwise the generated input fields will not be submitted with the form

Comment: @Dark - the code for the generated fields doesn't appear in source view.

Comment: @Pavel - generated input fields submit OK.  I've added the whole page.

Comment: @NickIredale You can get the generated code by using the developer tools of your browser. In Chrome for example you can right click the element and select "Inspect element". Adding your entire page unfortunately made your question less readable.

Answer (score 0):

use this style:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: the styling makes no difference to it.  It's got to all be in the Javascript.